# Deploying AWS SAM function with least privileges

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-sam

For a SAM CI/CD credentials like https://github.com/TractorZoom/sam-cli-action how do I create/specify a key/secret with the least privileges ? i.e. not my PowerUser account's **AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID** & **AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY**, but still enough to deploy and update the application?

When I do a `sam deploy` it says it's creating a IAM role, but on inspection it simply a arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole which only allows to write logs AFAICT.

So how does one create a "deployment role" with least privileges or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an IAM role with least privileges policies, and allow for your user to assume the role, then injecting the temp credentials to your CI/CD file. More info [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-assume-role-cli/)

Better yet, if you have an instance executing your pipeline, you could attach the IAM role to it. I use Gitlab runners and this is what I always go for. In this scenario, you can skip defining the credentials since the instance takes care of that.

Either case an IAM role is a pre-req, preferably an independent deployment.

Comment: So the workflow would be to assume the role, deploy, fail, add privileges, deploy etc and create the policy that way?

Comment: Usually you have some idea of what the role will need access to, and write that out initially, then cycle through a few times and fine tune. For instance, you could allow the role to create/manage lambdas with a certain prefix, same for DynamoDB tables and so on. There's always one you can't anticipate, so a few iterations is commonplace.